# Downloading jQuery UI CSS from Google's CDN

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, cdn, google-ajax-libraries

I am planning on using Google to download the jQuery lib for both UI and Core. My question is, do they allow me to download the CSS for it or should I have to host it myself?

Also if I use Google to load how should I load other plugins?  Can I compress all plugins together or should it be its own separate file?

Answer (score 580, accepted):

The Google AJAX Libraries API, which includes jQuery UI (currently v1.10.3), also includes popular themes as per the [jQuery UI blog](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2013/05/jquery-ui-1-10-3/):

**Google Ajax Libraries API (CDN)**

- Uncompressed: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js
- Compressed: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js
- Themes Uncompressed:
  [black-tie](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css), [blitzer](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css), [cupertino](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css), [dark-hive](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css), [dot-luv](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css), [eggplant](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css), [excite-bike](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css), [flick](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css), [hot-sneaks](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css), [humanity](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css), [le-frog](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css), [mint-choc](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css), [overcast](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css),[pepper-grinder](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css), [redmond](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css), [smoothness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css), [south-street](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css), [start](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/start/jquery-ui.css), [sunny](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css), [swanky-purse](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/swanky-purse/jquery-ui.css), [trontastic](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.css), [ui-darkness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css), [ui-lightness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css), and [vader](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css).
- Themes Compressed:
  [black-tie](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.min.css), [blitzer](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.min.css), [cupertino](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css), [dark-hive](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.min.css), [dot-luv](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.min.css), [eggplant](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.min.css), [excite-bike](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.min.css), [flick](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.min.css), [hot-sneaks](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.min.css), [humanity](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.min.css), [le-frog](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.min.css), [mint-choc](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.min.css), [overcast](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.min.css),[pepper-grinder](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.min.css), [redmond](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css), [smoothness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css), [south-street](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.min.css), [start](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/start/jquery-ui.min.css), [sunny](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.min.css), [swanky-purse](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/swanky-purse/jquery-ui.min.css), [trontastic](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.min.css), [ui-darkness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css), [ui-lightness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css), and [vader](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/vader/jquery-ui.min.css).

Comment: Note that these CSS scripts are not currently compressed/minimised, meaning that you could offer reduced size versions (by about 26% according to Google's PageSpeed plugin for Firefox) from your own domain, which might be faster for your users if your connection is decent and they don't already have the file cached locally.

Comment: every time i want to find this CDN I type "jquery ui css google cdn" and this post is the most direct way to the list of them all.. I just want to thank you +1

Comment: @Drew: Or he might use Reducisaurus too. :)

Comment: @Alix, thanks for [the link](http://code.google.com/p/reducisaurus/).  Looks like a useful service.

Comment: You can also CUT OUT the minor version numbers from the URL to automatically grab the latest CSS/JS, always. Just leave the major version number in place. Example: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: @miCRoSCoPiC_eaRthLinG you may want to avoid doing that, actually, since Google sets very short cache times on the non-fully-specified versions of libraries. It was only around an hour the last time I checked.

Comment: You also wouldn't want to get the latest version without testing that it still works. For instance, the base theme is no longer included in the CDN build and the link in the answer is broken. You can also get the minified versions from Google's CDN. ie [smoothness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css)

Comment: To get the minified CSS from Google CDN, just replace .css with .min.css

Comment: Note, to include the above links in your code, leave out the protocol, e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/etc" />` and that way it will always include the correct version depending on the protocol requested by the user. Same goes for including jQuery and jQuery UI JS files.

Comment: jQuery-ui is now at version 1.10.4.  Just update the version in the above.  Google's Hosted Libraries - Developer's Guide is a great resource for all of the Google-hosted library CDN names.  https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui

Comment: The domain `ajax.googleapis.com` supports HTTPS...there's no harm in using HTTPS all the time as opposed to protocol relative URLs. Also, here's a how-to on adding sub-resource integrity to your script tags -> https://blog.cdemi.io/using-subresource-integrity-sri-with-public-cdns/

Answer (score 67):

jQuery now has a CDN access:

code.jquery.com/ui/**[version]**/themes/**[theme name]**/jquery-ui.css

---

And to make this  a little more easy, Here you go:

- base: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
- black-tie: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css
- blitzer: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css
- cupertino: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css
- dark-hive: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css
- dot-luv: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css
- eggplant: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css
- excite-bike: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css
- flick: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css
- hot-sneaks: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css
- humanity: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css
- le-frog: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css
- mint-choc: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css
- overcast: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css
- pepper-grinder: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css
- redmond: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css
- smoothness: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
- south-street: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css
- start: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css
- sunny: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css
- swanky-purse: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/swanky-purse/jquery-ui.css
- trontastic: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.css
- ui-darkness: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css
- ui-lightness: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css
- vader: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css

Comment: It supports https now (at least since the time of this post)

Comment: How can you use the images associated with this CDN, there are missing locaaly and I don't want to download them. Is there a way to use the one stored in the CDN ?

Comment: @BaptistePernet: The CDN also provides all the associated images, and as the `url` statements are all relative to the `css` file location, the client will automatically grab the images from the CDN

Answer (score 29):

Google is hosting jQueryUI css at this link https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css

If you look at this code directly, it is importing the css using @import [which can be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022715/745). You may want to factor the import into its parts to gain a slight performance benefit:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css

Answer (score 7):

As Obama says "Yes We Can". Here is the link to it. [developers.google.com/#jquery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

You need to use

**Google**

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/[VERSION NO]/jquery-ui.min.js
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/[VERSION NO]/themes/[THEME NAME]/jquery-ui.min.css
```

**jQuery CDN**

```
code.jquery.com/ui/[VERSION NO]/jquery-ui.min.js
code.jquery.com/ui/[VERSION NO]/themes/[THEME NAME]/jquery-ui.min.css
```

**Microsoft**

```
ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/[VERSION NO]/jquery-ui.min.js
ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/[VERSION NO]/themes/[THEME NAME]/jquery-ui.min.css
```

Find theme names here http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ in gallery subtab

.

But i would **not recommend** you hosting from cdn for the following reasons

1. Although your chance of hit rate is good in case of Google CDN compared to others but it's still abysmally low.(any cdn not just google).
2. Loading via cdn you will have 3 requests one for jQuery.js, one for jQueryUI.js and one for your code.  You might as will compress it on your local and load it as one single resource.

http://zoompf.com/blog/2010/01/should-you-use-javascript-library-cdns

Comment: The article you linked is from 2010. Most of the data he mentioned is outdated. There is a much better hit rate now, a lot more websites are using Google CDN now than back in 2010.

Comment: Here are updated statistics:
http://blog.cloudharmony.com/2015/02/cdn-marketshare-alexa-fortune-500.html
The majority of websites seem to use CDNs now.
More data:
http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/cd-jquerycdn/all/all

Answer (score 5):

I would think so. Why not? Wouldn't be much of a CDN w/o offering the CSS to support the script files

[This link](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_17_now_released/) suggests that they are:

> We find it particularly exciting that
>   the jQuery UI CSS themes are now
>   hosted on Google's Ajax Libraries CDN.

Comment: I tried adding loading it using google load statement...would not load the css....checked it.

Comment: here's an example url that seems to work: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 5):

You could use this one if you mean the jQuery UI css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI < 1.13 is considered a security vulnerability now by Google Page Speed Insights.

Use a security-fixed more current version instead.  As of 2022 this would be 1.13.2

Ex:

- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js

  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css

Full HTML Tag Examples:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```