# jQueryUI widgets

Tags: jquery-ui

How do I work with widgets?  Here's what I've got so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.load("jqueryui", "1");
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-widget-header">
        header
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        content
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a nice little div with a shaded header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need added to your current code is the stylesheet to make those lovely classes have some meaning, like this:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

[Here's your example with that theme (dot-luv)](http://jsbin.com/unuqi/edit)

For other themes, [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/jquery-css-download-from-google), just change the version number in the url from `1.7.0` to current, which is `1.8` as of this answer time.  Alternatively, you can [design your own theme in ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and point to *that* stylesheet :)

Comment: Thanks Nick!  It struck me as I was walking the dog tonight that I forgot to include the stylesheet.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As easy as 1, 2, 3 and 4

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My Html</title>

    <!-- 1. Include the javascript files -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- 2. Include the CSS files (you can change the theme changing /base/ -->    
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- 3. Add the markup for the widget you want (see below) -->    

    <!-- 4. Call the jQuery UI javascript function that performs the magic -->    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
      });
      </script>


</head>
<body>

<!-- 3. Add the markup for the widget you want -->    
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>

        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">

        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The UI effect are mostly obtained with the use of css files.

You can use javascript to make some effects that play with add and remove class from an element.

[JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is a good example of some effects.