# jQuery UI Datepicker - why's it naked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI Datepicker and hooked it with a text field in the simplest way possible.

```
$('#date').datepicker();
```

But when I click the text field, the Datepicker looks like this:

[image]

Why's that? Do I need to install skin or something?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to add a reference to the jquery ui stylesheet.

Comment: Oh you've got a cute little datepicker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add the css file to the page. it should come in the same package js + css

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you add the appropriate .css reference to your page. Perhaps it came in your downloaded bundle, perhaps not.

For a quick and dirty reference during development/testing, use:

```
<link href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Take a local copy for production use.

Answer (score 4):

Google also hosts the css files for jquery. As referenced here

[Downloading jQuery UI CSS from Google's CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-css-from-googles-cdn)

Just modify the version number to what version of jquery ui you are using

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 1):

More than likely there's a CSS file that was supposed to come with it.