# JQuery issue - http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css not working

Tags: jquery

I have never used J Query....Was wondering what does the link ..

http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css

link to?
One of the websites i have taken over has stopped working. When i take this source out at the top of the page it works, when i put it back in stops working again?

For now i have taken it out, but i assume jquery server has gone down or something. What does this source do and is it ok to leave it out? thanks

Comment: Is it actually a rel='stylesheet' link or what?

Comment: its a css style, which means you are loading a style that is hosted on jquery. use can use googles, api aswell which is more reliable or you could just host it on your own webpage, that way your page won't have to rely on jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery disabled hotlinking to the files hosted on their server. You shouldn't be linking directly like that. Instead use the CDNs offered by google or microsoft.

Use this link for your CSS : http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

And the others are available too 
http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI

This question has answers on how to get the other themes 
[Downloading jQuery UI CSS from Google's CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-css-from-googles-cdn)

Comment: Did they happen to disable that today?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact date was, but I remember seeing it on either there site or their blog that they will be disabling hotlinking soon (saw it a while back). Apparently their server was slowing down because people copied the code of their old examples which linked to their main server instead of the CDN

Comment: Ahh, found the link : http://blog.jquery.it/2010/12/30/hotlinking-to-be-disabled-on-jan-31-2011/ From jan 31st

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google server instead.
http://www.stemkoski.com/jquery-ui-1-7-2-themes-list-at-google-code/