# Where can I get more jQuery UI themes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know there are some cool themes on the jQuery website, but I need more.   Anyone know where I can get more?

I found two links: [here](http://www.michaelvanderheeren.be/?p=382) and [here](https://github.com/taitems/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme).

Comment: I think what you are looking for is jQuery plugins that have been designed to work with theme roller, which is used by the jQuery UI library.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a list of JQuery UI themes here: http://www.mightywebdeveloper.com/design/jquery-ui-themes/.

Good thing is that these themes are not just themeroller themes, they are completely skinned with a different look.

Comment: 404 Not Found error

Comment: If anyone has an updated link please share

Comment: https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1350748739-Free-jQuery-UI-themes

Answer (score 10):

There are the standard ones as listed in the accepted answer on this question: [Downloading jQuery UI CSS from Google's CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-ui-css-from-googles-cdn)

Or you can [roll your own](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

I guess it depends on your definition of 'cool' really... using the standard themes and pulling the files from the Google CDN will offer the best performance, which is pretty cool ;)

Comment: Your first link is down

Comment: @kukis Cheers, took me a while to get around to it but I've updated that so it points to the active question rather than the closed duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Check the repo [here](http://www.devinrolsen.com/jquery-google-hosted-repository-links/)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution, I think, is to [Roll Your Own](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) in Jquery UI website. Also, you can find some interesting themes in gallery section.

If you don't want these themes, there is a website where you can find a lot of custom Jquery UI themes. http://jqueryuithemegallery.just-page.de/ but it's down at the moment.

For some themes see [here](http://www.devinrolsen.com/jquery-google-hosted-repository-links/) too.

Comment: Thanks, but it's something more than changing a few colors -> http://themeforest.net/item/white-label-a-full-featured-admin-skin/270758

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know anything else, but if there will be something new I will let you know )))

Comment: http://jqueryuithemegallery.just-page.de/ link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Here's list of sources, including hosted by google:

http://blog.jqueryui.com/2015/03/jquery-ui-1-11-4/