# Change the sytle of datepicker using jquery-ui

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker, cdn

How can I change the style of the calender using the css files of jquery-ui?

```
<input type="text" id="dob"/>
```

here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("#dob").datepicker();
});
```

here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/zncSh/2/ ?

how can I format it  to be like this http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ ??

where should I add the css class ?

Comment: That jsFiddle doesn't include jQuery or jQuery UI. [This one does](http://jsfiddle.net/kLj9B/).

Comment: I update my jsFiddle, but what should I add in the CSS part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to link to a theme file, either to one of the preset ones or use the [theme roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to create one. You should have a read at [how jQuery UI themes work](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming).

Here's the post that list the remote repositories:
[Downloading jQuery UI CSS from Google's CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-css-from-googles-cdn)

I modified your jsfiddle to include the base theme: http://jsfiddle.net/zncSh/3/