# How to make web.py and jQuery UI work together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, web.py

Can jQuery UI be used with web.py?  With jQuery and web.py, you can trigger events using jQuery or $$ (because $ is used by web.py for template variables) - but the same does not seem to be true with jQuery UI.

I get the following error from the code below: jQuery("#dialog").dialog is not a function.  The same code executes correctly outside of web.py framework.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/usr/local/pos/templates/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){

            // Dialog           
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() { 
                        jQuery(this).dialog("close"); 
                    }, 
                    "Cancel": function() { 
                        jQuery(this).dialog("close"); 
                    } 
                }
            });

            // Dialog Link
            jQuery('#dialog_link').click(function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });             
        });

    </script>   
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>  

    <h2>Dialog</h2>
    <a href="#" id="dialog_link">Open Dialog</a>

    <!-- ui-dialog -->
    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not properly loading jQuery UI.

```
/usr/local/pos/templates/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js
```

looks like it should be a http URL instead - you don't want to use a local filesystem path. (if it's meant to be a relative filesystem path, double-check whether it's correct.)

Make sure you are using the right URL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but with jQuery UI I have not found an http URL to use.  The site points to downloading: http://jqueryui.com/download.  Since this code works correctly outside of the web.py framework, I believe the library is being loaded correctly.

Comment: @Nora where is your copy of the jQuery UI library located? What URL do the other pages use to load it?

Comment: my jQuery UI library is in /usr/local/pos/templates/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js, I'm using a absolute path to eliminate any difference between the code executed outside of web.py and within the framework.

Comment: @Nora can you confirm in Chrome's or Firebug's "Network" tabs that that JS file is in fact getting loaded? eg. http://getfirebug.com/network I'm willing to bet a large beer that there's something funky with the file and it's not getting loaded

Comment: beer on me!  Thanks so much.  I was loading static files incorrectly in web.py.  I needed to put it in a separate folder - http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old post but I feel that this might help too.  You said that you could not find an http to use instead of the local version.  Google hosts several java-script libraries on their CDN. You can view this info here - https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Just click on the library you want. They have both jquery and jquery ui with exactly what you need to paste.

If you want the CSS files for jquery ui, you can find links to those here - [Downloading jQuery UI CSS from Google's CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-css-from-googles-cdn) (the first/best answer)