# DatePicker Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm a newbie.
While im working on datepicker, somehow it is not working properly on IE.
Please check the below image[image]

and here is the code:

```
function pageLoad() {
        $(function () {
            $("#textBox").datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "someImageUrl", 
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: "M dd,yy",
                buttonText: "Select date"
            })
        });
        $("#textBox").val(defaultDate);
    }
```

here are the versions of JQuery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Sorry here are the CSS:

```
<link id="lnkStyleSheet" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: It would seem that you haven't loaded the jQuery UI CSS file(s).

Comment: Have you included the jQuery UI CSS (theme)? [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) / [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-ui-css-from-googles-cdn)

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery UI CSS?

Comment: <link id="lnkStyleSheet" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"/>

Comment: This behavior uccurs only on IE? On wich version of IE are you testing?

Comment: yes unfortunately i have to test only on IE im testing on IE 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the CSS and images that come with jQuery UI.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
```

See the "Basic Overview: Using jQuery UI on a Web Page" section here: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Comment: A little more information would be helpful in making this a complete answer.

Comment: @DenimChicken: I'm looking for this kind of functionality: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: It appears to be a CSS issue so I'd follow the basic overview and confirm that the CSS and image files are loading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own theme and use those files

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

```
   <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Just add it in your HTML head before  code