# jQuery UI | datepicker problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

If you have seen the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) page before, you will notice the widgets they have.

I have been using their datepicker widget and have got it working successfully. 
However it loads up blank as i have not made the CSS for it yet. In their source, you can see that they link to a css file.

Is there anyway I can obtain the CSS that is use? Here is a link for the widget for more information:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: Appreciate and information, thanks

Comment: You can use the same CSS they use or make your own theme at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: Oh sorry, i see. Thanks alot for this. Make an answer and i can vote it

Comment: Related (or possibly duplicate?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example uses [smoothness](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css) theme, as you can see from the source. You can as well create your own themes using the [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to create custom themes as pointed out in comments by j08691.